# Flutter BLoC - state doesn't triggers widget rebuild

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

the app is simple categories/products display , everything works fine except select a product from a category products and swip back to the products widget , the state changes and it's neither one of the states i created and just shows a loading indicator ( ProductsWrapper default return from state).

so here is the code :

ProductBloc :

```
class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {
  final ProductRepository productRepository;

  ProductBloc({required this.productRepository}) : super(ProductsEmpty());

  @override
  Stream<Transition<ProductEvent, ProductState>> transformEvents(
      Stream<ProductEvent> events,
      TransitionFunction<ProductEvent, ProductState> transitionFn) {
    return super.transformEvents(
        events.debounceTime(const Duration(microseconds: 500)), transitionFn);
  }

  @override
  Stream<ProductState> mapEventToState(ProductEvent event) async* {
    if (event is FetchProducts) {
      yield* _mapFetchProductsToState(event);
    } else if (event is RefreshProducts) {
      yield* _mapRefreshProductsToState(event);
    } else if (event is FetchProduct) {
      yield* _mapFetchProductToState(event);
    } else if (event is RefreshProduct) {
      yield* _mapRefreshProductToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<ProductState> _mapFetchProductsToState(FetchProducts event) async* {
    try {
      final products =
          (await productRepository.getCategoryProducts(event.categoryId));
      yield ProductsLoaded(products: products.products!);
    } catch (_) {
      yield state;
    }
  }

  Stream<ProductState> _mapRefreshProductsToState(
      RefreshProducts event) async* {
    try {
      final products =
          await productRepository.getCategoryProducts(event.categoryId);
      yield ProductsLoaded(products: products.products!);
      return;
    } catch (_) {
      yield state;
    }
  }

  Stream<ProductState> _mapFetchProductToState(FetchProduct event) async* {
    try {
      final product =
          (await productRepository.getProductDetails(event.productId));
      yield ProductLoaded(product: product);
    } catch (e) {
      yield state;
    }
  }

  Stream<ProductState> _mapRefreshProductToState(RefreshProduct event) async* {
    try {
      final product =
          await productRepository.getProductDetails(event.productId);
      yield ProductLoaded(product: product);
      return;
    } catch (_) {
      yield state;
    }
  }
}
```

states :

```
abstract class ProductState extends Equatable {
  const ProductState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class ProductsEmpty extends ProductState {}

class ProductEmpty extends ProductState {}

class ProductLoading extends ProductState {}

class ProductsLoading extends ProductState {}

class ProductLoaded extends ProductState {
  final Product product;

  const ProductLoaded({required this.product});

  ProductLoaded copyWith({required Product product}) {
    return ProductLoaded(product: product);
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [product];
  @override
  String toString() => 'ProductLoaded { product: ${product.name}}';
}

class ProductsLoaded extends ProductState {
  final List<Product> products;

  const ProductsLoaded({required this.products});

  ProductsLoaded copyWith({required List<Product> products}) {
    return ProductsLoaded(products: products);
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [products];
  @override
  String toString() => 'ProductLoaded { products: ${products.length}}';
}

class ProductError extends ProductState {}
```

ProductRepository ( ProductApiService is just the api and it's working fine ) :

```
class ProductRepository {
  final ProductApiService productApiService;
  ProductRepository({ProductApiService? productApiService})
      : productApiService = productApiService ?? ProductApiService();

  Future<Products> getCategoryProducts(int? categoryId) async {
    return productApiService.fetchCategoryProducts(categoryId);
  }

  Future<Product> getProductDetails(int? productId) async {
    return productApiService.fetchProductDetails(productId);
  }
}
```

ProductsWrapper :

```
  final int? categoryId;

  const ProductsWrapper({Key? key, required this.categoryId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductsWrapperState createState() => _ProductsWrapperState();
}

class _ProductsWrapperState extends State<ProductsWrapper> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _scrollThreshold = 200;
  Completer _productsRefreshCompleter = new Completer();

  List<Product> products = [];
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _onScroll() {
    final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
      context
          .read<ProductBloc>()
          .add(FetchProducts(categoryId: widget.categoryId!));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context
        .read<ProductBloc>()
        .add(FetchProducts(categoryId: widget.categoryId!));
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
    _productsRefreshCompleter = Completer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double itemHeight = 260;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: BlocListener<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is ProductsLoaded) {
                products = state.products;
                _productsRefreshCompleter.complete();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is ProductsLoading) {
                    print('a7a');
                    return Center(
                      child: LoadingIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  if (state is ProductsLoaded) {
                    products = state.products;
                    if (state.products.isEmpty) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text("No Products Found in this category"),
                      );
                    }

                    return Scaffold(
                      body: SafeArea(
                        child: Container(
                          child: GridView.builder(
                              itemCount: products.length,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              gridDelegate:
                                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                                      childAspectRatio:
                                          (itemWidth / itemHeight)),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                                    elevation: 0,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    ProductDetailScreen(
                                                        productId:
                                                            products[index]
                                                                .id)));
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            ClipRRect(
                                              child: Image.network(
                                                products[index]
                                                    .image!
                                                    .image
                                                    .toString(),
                                                height: 150,
                                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                products[index].name.toString(),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                      '\$${products[index].price.toString()}'),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      right: 8.0),
                                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                                    backgroundColor:
                                                        Theme.of(context)
                                                            .primaryColor,
                                                    radius: 10,
                                                    child: IconButton(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        Icons.add,
                                                        size: 20,
                                                      ),
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      onPressed: () {},
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }                  
                  return Center(
                    child: LoadingIndicator(strokeWidth: 5.0,),
                  );
                }))));
  }
}
```

ProductDetailScreen :

```
class ProductDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? productId;
  const ProductDetailScreen({Key? key, required this.productId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductDetailScreenState createState() => _ProductDetailScreenState();
}

class _ProductDetailScreenState extends State<ProductDetailScreen> {
  Completer _productRefreshCompleter = new Completer();
  Product product = new Product();
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<ProductBloc>().add(FetchProduct(productId: widget.productId));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: BlocListener<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is ProductLoaded) {
            product = state.product;
            _productRefreshCompleter.complete();
            _productRefreshCompleter = Completer();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          child: BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is ProductLoading) {
                return Center(
                  child: LoadingIndicator(),
                );
              }
              if (state is ProductLoaded) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(product.name.toString()),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Center(
                child: LoadingIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 5.0,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated .

thanks for taking time reading this , have a nice day and stay safe.

Comment: something is definitely triggering the event. Probably your ScrollController's listener

Comment: @MozesOng i think my explanation is fague.

let me explain it :

when using Navigator push to change from page A to page B, I expect page A to be disposed and page B to be initialized and this would allow me to perform a clean up on page A. here page A is not disposed , It is kept in the navigator history .

i hope this give you an idea of what i'm facing , thanks

Comment: When you navigate from page A to page B, page A will not be disposed of. It is still on the navigation stack. This is normal behaviour. Maybe what you can do is call an event before you navigate to page B?

Comment: Or maybe you can Navigator.of(context).pop() to pop Page A before you navigate to page B. Then when you pop page B, u can re-render page A again, to make it seem that page A is still below Page B. The navigation animation will trigger again tho.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using one bloc to do 2 things. The products list is an entity, the single detail is another entity. And you need to use the properties of the states as a result inside blocBuilders.
Plus, you don't need any listener and completer. The bloc pattern refreshes all when state changes.
I have created a repo with a working solution.
https://github.com/eugenioamato/categoryproducts